# If I bring travellers cheques will it work and if so how much money will I need for 7 days in Italy?

Tags: money, italy

I want to go on holiday to Italy for my university summer vacation for seven days from Pakistan but I don't have a bank account.

If I bring travellers cheques will it work and if so how much money will I need for 7 days?

Comment: I understand the assets you're trying to spend are Pakistani Rupees, cash?

Comment: Are you asking about (a) how to pay for an airline ticket, (b) how to bring money to spend during the holiday, (c) how to demonstrate your ability to pay for yourself in a visa application, (d) how to show proof of funds when you land, or something entirely different?

Comment: Why don't you open a bank account?

Comment: @rvs perhaps the cost of opening a bank account is so great that it is not justified by the benefits.

Comment: @phoog how much would it typically cost? I did a quick search and I've found a website that offers account with 50 Rs (0.4 EUR) / month fee + 0.05% fee for "Inter City" transactions, whatever it means. Does not look too bad.
This is genuine curiosity, I know nothing about Pakistan so I wonder if it's really a problem there.

Comment: @rvs according to Wikipedia, Pakistan's median monthly wage in 2009 was USD 255.  I suppose a university student has a considerably smaller budget than the median wage.  In that case, USD 0.50 starts to look more significant.  In any event, opening a bank account solely because of the visa application is also going to look suspicious.  It's probably better to show the bank records of he person who will be supplying the money for the trip.

Answer (score 4):

Not having a bank account isn't an issue while you are in Europe. However, assuming you are a Pakistani national, you will need to apply for a visa, which will include providing your financial details. Not having a bank account may be a red flag in the visa process.

While you are in Europe your problem will be be not having a credit card. Having a credit card (or debit card) is considered normal in Europe, and not having one is going to place you at a disadvantage, though not necessarily an insurmountable one. (If bizarrely you have a credit card but no bank account, just use that for everything).

Not having a credit card will make it difficult for you to book an airline ticket. You will need to do this through a travel agent rather than with an airline, so you can hand over cash.

In Europe most hotels will ask for a credit card, and if you don't have one may ask you to pay in advance. It will be more diffcult to reserve a hotel in advance without a credit card. Some hotels won't do it, some might insist that you arrive before a certain time to confirm your reservation in person. Other major purchases like train tickets will be more complicated, and require you to do them in person. Don't even think about trying to rent a car.

Travellers cheques, while once popular, are now extremely unpopular because they are easy to forge. You can no longer use them as a cash substitute - you will need to go to a bank and exchange them, bringing official photo id with you, and taking substantial time. They are better than cash in that if they are lost or stolen you can get the money replaced, but you will need to exchange them periodically for local cash and use that.

Comment: So, in short, you need a visa and a Visa?